# How to replace an element in a list at specific index

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Reading [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.AddingListElements), they say I could add an element in a list, but I'm trying and it keeps adding a new item to document with key as `arrayName[index]`, like following:

I'm trying with this query:

```
    await documentClient.transactWrite({
      TransactItems: [{
        Update: {
          TableName: recordsTable,
          Key: { id: selectedRec.id },
          UpdateExpression: 'SET #k1 = :v1',
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#k1': `occurrences[${idx}]`, // idx = 245
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':v1': selectedOccurrence, // a map object
          },
        }
      }, {
         // another query irrelevant to problem
      }]
    }).promise();
```

And this is how this document ends:

[image]

It should replace object in index `245` in `occurrences` array, but instead it added a new map with key `occurrences[245]` into my doc.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try without the attribute name mapping? For example: UpdateExpression: `SET occurrences[${idx}] = :v1`

Comment: @jarmod, yeah, it did work! buy why doesn't work using `ExpressionAttributeNames`?

Comment: Not sure why the name substitution step isn’t supported but I’m not surprised. Possibly related to the order in which things are evaluated. You might also try: UpdateExpression: SET #k1[${idx}] = :v1 still supplying the attribute name mapping to see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include subscripts in `ExpressionAttributeNames`. You can only indicate attribute names.

There are a couple of ways to solve this:

```
UpdateExpression: `SET #k1[${idx}] = :v1`,
ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#k1': 'occurrences' }
```

or:

```
UpdateExpression: `SET occurrences[${idx}] = :v1`
```

Note that the second solution will not work if your attribute name is a [reserved word](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html).